How to set secure-file-priv to empty in VSCode SQL?
As I'm loading csv data to SQL, I get error message and didn't manage to resolve it.
The code was:
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/xxx/Desktop/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE num;

The message I received was
The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

I tried using LOCAL INFILE and it still didn't work.
I tried secure-file-priv="" . But it's read only so I couldn't change it.
I also tried locating the cnf file in terminal, but no such file was found.
As I'm using vscode, instead of workbench, I couldn't use the method to change advanced setting at the connection.

The error tells the cause, you need to remove that flag from the command line that started the server, you can't do it from the client.

in widow it is a ini file and it located in

I tried directly setting secure-file-priv="" in terminal, but it won't work since it's read-only. And I tried a lot of methods to find cnf file but couldn't. Since I don't have much knowledge of using the terminal. Is there any way to locate or create the cnf file in terminal (mac)? Thank you!
